# Data model for a tagging system in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How can I model a dynamoDB table to build a tag system in which products can have multiple tags assigned, and we should be able to filter the set of products that have a particular tag or collection of tags and to obtain all tags assigned to a given product?

I considered having a table with:

> HASH Key : deviceId
>
> RANGE Key : tag

This allows to query all tags for a device.

Then I would need a GSI with:

> HASH Key : tag
>
> RANGE Key : deviceId

To filter all devices with a given tag. But this won't let me filter by multiple tags at the same time without involving multiple queries to the GSI and processing at application level.

Is there any good solution for this problem in DynamoDB?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?  I am interested.

Comment: Any solution? I'm also curious!

Comment: No dynamodb does not solve this pattern efficiently,

Answer (score 0):

> But this won't let me filter by multiple tags at the same time without involving multiple queries to the GSI and processing at application level.

A workaround using filter conditions:

1. Add a boolean attribute for each device tag
2. Query for the first tag out of your multiple tags using the GSI (just like you'd query for all devices with given tag)
3. Finally use a [filter condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#FilteringResults) to check for the remaining tags, matching for the boolean attributes of step 1

No need for multiple requests or client side aggregation, and thanks to step 2 we avoid doing a full table scan.

Note that this query is still suboptimal in the sense that we end up scanning those devices that have the first tag but lack some of the remaining tags.

Comment: Just a note: this would work only for cases when you want to select items with *all* these tags present. I think more often people are looking for union, not intersection